# dyson shell world, how do you create artificial gravity so people can stand on the inside of the shell?

Tags: science-fiction, space-constructs, megastructures

one of the ideas I had is to make the Dyson shell a series of bands(made from impossible material with extreme tensile strength) and then spin these bands at different speeds, with the "land masses" attached to this band, like scales. Using centrifugal force to create gravity pushing on the people, is this even viable? maybe there are more obvious solutions i did not think about,

Comment: Hello Koi. Stack Exchange does not permit you to provide an answer to your own question and then ask for more answers (see [help/dont-ask]). This stack does allow you to present an idea and have it judged using the [tag:internal-consistency] tag, but you've not met the requirements of that tag. To be honest, asking, "is X feasible/viable/possible/realistic?" is problematic on a site that's dedicated to helping build imaginary worlds (see [help/on-topic]). There is no working antigravity other than centrifugal force that we know of. However...

Comment: the question of how to create artificial gravity has been asked before on this Stack. If that's what you're asking, your question is probably a [duplicate of this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/58264/40609). If not, you should review the questions tagged [tag:artificial-gravity] and see if they answer your question. If they don't, explaining why would help us answer this question.

Comment: Could you also give a bit of context. What's the purpose of this shell? Do the inhabitants even know that there *is* an outside?

Comment: Do you need to use the *whole* inner surface? It depends on the radius of the sphere but usually the inside of a Dyson sphere is *incomprehensibly* vast.

Answer (score 1):

If you have materials that allows it, rotation would do the job.

Another option is to put everything on outside surface of static bands. In this case star gravity is used. It unlikely to work with Sun, the band has to be rather small for it but there are all kinds of stars. I think you would need compressive strength in this case from your impossible material. And some artificial illumination, obviously.